# PHP errors: 'call to undefined function' or 'undefined variable' happening sporadically on TestRail

Tags: php, iis

Me and my team have problem with TestRail running with PHP on IIS 8.5.

From time to time our TestRail instance becomes unresponsive with an error of following kind:

[image: TestRail PHP error call to undefined function]
OR

```
PHP Error: Cannot redeclare class library in testrail\sys\base\library.php at 21
```

OR

```
Undefined variable: case
```

OR

```
Undefined variable: GI
```

(Every time undefined variable is different)

Memory limit is set to 4GB in php.ini, which should be plenty:

```
memory_limit = 4294967296
```

These errors get fixed by simple IIS server restart. But our team wants to avoid this issue at all, i.e. to stop getting these kinds of messages because TestRail gets unresponsive at very different times, which are difficult to predict and every time it requires a person with admin access to the application to fix this error. This becomes very annoying and inconvenient, especially for application users. It happened around 50 times this year with no sensible errors in the logs or any clue what might cause this problem. We haven't been able to fix it yet. Is it possible to fix this once and be sure it won’t happen again?

Thanks in advance for any ideas of how to handle this case.

Answer (score 0):

This does not look like an IIS issue. I would start by looking at the code in your php file.

For example:

1: PHP Error: Cannot redeclare class library in testrail\sys\base\library.php at 21- Means that you have already declared a call and trying to declare it again.

2: Undefined variable: case- Are you initializing the variable from a post or get or any array? You may have an field in that array.